# NextJS Request in Every Route Change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graph, graphql, next.js13

I have a NEXTJS 13 with Pages directory project. I want to request to our graphql server in every route change. And want to make it from server. But can i do it ? And even if I do it can I put this datas to my Redux store ?  Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 0):

[Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware) is run upon every request and could be used to implement additional logic to call a GraphQL server.